# Mock base class function called in derived class; to unit test derived class method. Base class instantiated in derived class constructor

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, googlemock

I m new to unit testing and need some help with this. I would like to test my Derived class function which has dependency on base class method.

```
class Base {
  Base(int a_, int b_){
     a = a_;
     b = b_;
  }
  int a;
  int b;

  int GetBaseValue(){
   return a + b;
  }
}

class Derived: public Base {
      Derived(int c,int a,int b): 
              c_(c),
              Base(a,b){}

      int GetDerivedValue(){
         return c + GetBaseValue();
      }
}
```

Comment: So do you want `Derived::GetValue()` to be `Base::GetValue() + c`?

Comment: Not actually i m not overriding the functions; they have different functionality. The code is correct.

Comment: Then what exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: `Derived` isn't deriving from `Base`. Or from anything, for that matter.

Comment: Ohh Sorry! I have updated to code, the derived inherits the base class

Comment: Create some `Derived` instances and make sure that `GetDerivedValue` has the results you expect. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: I want to unit test the GetDerivedValue. I am not able to mock the dependency of Derived (GetBaseValue method) as the base is getting instantiated during instantiation of Derived class.

Comment: So to explain in details, even if i create a mock class for the Base class (MockBaseClass); i m not able to call the mock functions of MockBaseClass as my Base class get instantiated in the derived class. I want my Derived class to use MockBaseClass but I dont' know how to do that.

Comment: @GauravChaudhari you can use technique called 'partial mock', see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To make your example work and test only `Derived` in separation from the `Base` class (BTW, `Base` should have it's own set of unit tests), you need to make `Base::GetBaseValue` a virtual method and mock it.

```
class Base {
    public:
    Base(int a_, int b_){
        a = a_;
        b = b_;
    }

    virtual int GetBaseValue(){
        return a + b;
    }
    
    private:
    int a;
    int b;
};

class Derived: public Base {
    public:
    Derived(int c,int a,int b): 
            c_(c),
            Base(a,b){}

    int GetDerivedValue(){
        return c_ + GetBaseValue();
    }

private:
    int c_;
};

class PartialDerivedMock : public Derived {
    public:
    using Derived::Derived;
    MOCK_METHOD(int, GetBaseValue, (), (override));
};


TEST(PartialDerivedMockTest, UseMockedGetBaseValue)
{
    PartialDerivedMock out{1, 2, 3};

    EXPECT_CALL(out, GetBaseValue()).WillOnce(testing::Return(42));

    ASSERT_EQ(out.GetDerivedValue(), 43);
}
```

But as you've used the keyword 'dependency' in your question: please let me give you some advice. Using inheritance is a very, very strong connection between two classes. Delegating some logically consistent parts of code to a separate class is great idea in OOP, but using inheritance to (re)use this code - not so much. Please consider this:

```
//now: with the dependency
class Dependency {
    public:
    ~Dependency() = default;
    virtual int GetValue() = 0;
};

class Dependant {
    public:
    Dependant(int c, Dependency& dep): 
            c_(c),
            dependency{dep}{}

    int GetSomeValue(){
        return c_ + dependency.GetValue();
    }

    private:
    int c_;
    Dependency& dependency;
};

class DependencyMock : public Dependency {
    public:
    MOCK_METHOD(int, GetValue, (), (override));
};

TEST(DependencyTest, UseMockedGetBaseValue)
{
    DependencyMock mock{};
    Dependant out{1, mock};

    EXPECT_CALL(mock, GetValue()).WillOnce(testing::Return(42));

    ASSERT_EQ(out.GetSomeValue(), 43);
}
```

Following SOLID principles you get the benefits of two classes doing separate things (S), the interface class not being modified when the implementation changes (O and L to some extent) and truly inverted dependency (D).

Working examples: https://godbolt.org/z/jM6vvGYzM